# TypeError: f() takes at least 1 argument (1 given) - Is this a bug in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using python 2.7.6 64 bit I type:

```
>>> def f(a, b=5):
...    pass
...
>>> f(b=3)
```

And then I get:

```
TypeError: f() takes at least 1 argument (1 given)
```

Of course I should get some error since I haven't assigned a value to the parameter `a`. But the error message I get doesn't mean anything (1 is at least 1).

This is a bug, right? Was it fixed? I couldn't find anything about it.

Thanks!

Comment: Whether you call this a bug is a matter of opinion. In any case, in Python 3 you get a better error message (`f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'`).

Comment: How is this a matter of opinion? I can get it to say "f() takes at least 1 argument (2 given)" in the same way. Will this be a matter of opinion either?

Comment: It's misleading but technically you did give one argument. But if you believe you already know the answer to your question, why ask it?

Comment: It's not a bug, just a bad/misleading error message.

Comment: @interjay The question is was the bug fixed or at least was it reported. And yes I gave one argument but the error here is that it says that the function takes at least on argument

Comment: As @interjay said, it's not a bug, it's a documentation problem. As interjay also said, this error message was improved for Python 3.

Comment: A problem, not a bug... OK

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not a bug.

To show this you can run the function with just the `a` value:

```
def f(a, b=5):
    print b

a=1
f(a)
```

Output:

```
>>> 
5
```

As you can see, the program prints out the value of `b` which is 5. You don't even have to pass `b` into the function because it is already defined by the function itself.

If you were to pass `f(b=3)`, like you did, you'd get an error that is asking you to input the `a` variable, because it has *not yet been defined anywhere.*

```
TypeError: f() takes at least 1 argument (1 given) #You've given 1 value (b=3), but 1 argument ("a" value) is still needed
```

That's why if you run:

```
>>> f(a=3)
5
```

You won't get any errors, because the `a` value has successfully been passed into the function.

---

**EDIT:**

To break it down even further:

- `a` and `b` are arguments

When it says `f() takes at least 1 argument`, it means that the function `f()` **can be used with only one argument passed to it**. But that single argument *must be* *`a`.*

What you did was pass `b=3` to it. `b` is *also an argument* (thats why it says `(1 given)` in your error), but it is not the "required" argument.

Comment: Thanks but I know that there should be an error. As I said: "Of course I should get some error..."

Comment: @EllaShar My answer is telling you that the error message _does_ mean something. It tells you that you're missing an "argument". Since b has already been defined in the function, it is therefore not looking for `b`, but for `a`. It would have been better if they said "positional argument", because then that would specifically refer to `a`. But the error is not wrong in any sense.

Answer (score 1):

It takes at least 1 argument since you can omit b and you did input 1 argument, the message error is not very helpful but not wrong either.

Comment: I just had "TypeError: launch_clients() takes at least 7 arguments (12 given)". Thanks a lot, python. 0% helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it this way:

The first portion of the sentence is counting the number of arguments with no default in the method signature (so, required arguments).

The second portion of the sentence is counting the total number of arguments actually passed to the method, regardless of if they're specified as keyword, positional, or of the method signature has a default for them.

It's not a very *helpful* error message, but it's not technically speaking wrong either. As others have said, the Python 3 version is a bit better, as it explicitly states that a *positional* argument is missing.